# How do I do Tag/synonym edits - moderator help needed perhaps?

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging

I've just realised I went and created a large number of multi-word tags that don't separate their words with dashes the way multi-word tags are supposed to.  Examples include:

[proofofstake, which should be proof-of-stake](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofofstake)
[proofofwork, which should be proof-of-work](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofofwork)
[performanceoptimisation, which should be performance-optimisation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performanceoptimisation)
[contractdesign, which should be contract-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contractdesign)
[denialofservice, which should be denial-of-service](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denialofservice)
etc.

Of course, I don't have enough reputation to correct the tags or create the appropriate tag synonyms.  What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

No problem. I renamed the tags.

There are no synonyms needed for this use case. Text completion will show users the correct tags.

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> → <kbd>denial-of-service</kbd>

Comment: Did you actually create further Tags with correct names, rather than renaming the bad Tags? If so, how did you rename them?

Comment: As a Moderator, I have the ability to rename tags. When there is larger tag cleanup, that is typically preferable to manually re-tagging each questions so it doesn't bump all those questions to the top of the 'activity' page.